# Не открывается собранный webpack(ом) проект vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

[image: В консоли нету ошибок, скрипт добавляет только BG]

```js
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'builder.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Подскажите, я собрал проект VUE.js с помощью webpack. Получился файл builder.js.
Но не получается его запустить. 
В чем возможна проблема? 
Или я как-то неправильно подключаю?
В настройках webpack? Если возможная проблема в настройках webpack, то я прикреплю webpack.config

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head> 
<body>
<script src="dist/builder.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Попробуйте для начала добавить детали вашей ошибки, может там текст какой-то есть. А так, еще попробуйте с путями поиграться, указать к примеру так: `<script src="/dist/builder.js"></script>` или так `<script src="./dist/builder.js"></script>`

Comment: @DenisBubnov, ошибки никакой нет. Такое чувство, будто не все скомпилировалось. Так как background-color: #000; работало... В js файл все скоипилировалось.

Comment: Странно...может чего глюкануло... попробуйте перезапустить проект, перестроить все. У меня если есть беда с `webpack`, то в консоли при запуске он пишет что не так.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, в смысле при запуске? Я сделал npm run build. Получился файл build.js. Открыл файл index.html. 
Как я понимаю, должно было все появиться, но ничего нету.

Comment: Я ещё npm start делаю  но у тебя в настройке этого нет. Не знаю, нужно копать. А путь менял как я писал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы `<div id="app"></div>` не забыли перед скриптом?

Comment: Только что как раз додумался. Именно в этом и была проблема!